# Showing users who liked an item in an item list

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

This is an issue that I've deemed impractical to implement but I would like to get some feedback to confirm.

I have a product and users database, where users can like products, the like data is stored in a reference table with just pid and uid.

The client request is to show 3 users who have liked every product in the product listing.

The problem is, its not possible to get this data in one query for the product listing,

How I once implemented and subsequently un-implemented it was to perform a request for the users who have liked the products during the loop through the product list.

ie.

```
foreach($prods as $row):
$likers = $this->model->get_likers($row->id);
endforeach;
```

That works, but obviously results in not only super slow product listings, and also creates a big strain on the database/cpu.

The final solution that was implemented was to only show the latest user who has liked it (this can be gotten from a join in the products list query) and have a link showing how many people have liked, and upon clicking on it, opens a ajax list of likers.

So my question is, is there actually a technique to show likers on the product list, or is it simply not possible to execute practically? I notice actually for most social media sites, they do not show all likers on the listings, and do employ the 'click to see likers' method. However, they do show comments per items on the listing, and this is actually involves the same problem doesn't it?

Edit: mock up attached on the desired outcome. there would be 30 products per page.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the results you're trying to get (including sample data / expected result is often helpful)? From what I understand you want a list of products, and for each product you want 3 people who have liked it?

Comment: Hi Alex, yeah what you understood is exactly what I mean. This is more of a concept/technique issue, so actual specific data doesn't really matter other than the idea that we have a list of products, and a list of users, users can like products, this user<->product relation is stored in an intersection table. So is it possible to list out say, 50 products per page, and show X number of users who like the products with fast loading times and easy on resources?

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL related solution because I think Pinterest uses Redis for these relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading your comment reply to Alex.Ritna ,yes you can get the x no. of results with per group ,using `GROUP_CONCAT()` and the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`  it will show  the likers seperated by comma or whatever separator you specified in the query (i have used ||).`ORDER BY` clause can be used in group_concat function.As there is no schema information is available so i assume you have one product table one user table and a junction table that maintains the relation of user and product.In the substring function i have used x=3

```
SELECT p.*,
COUNT(*) total_likes,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(u.firstname,'  ',u.lastname)  ORDER BY some_column DESC SEPARATOR '||'),
'||',3) x_no_of_likers
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN junction_table jt ON(p.id=jt.product_id)
INNER JOIN users u  ON(u.id=jt.user_id)
GROUP BY p.id
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a1f/10)

Now at your application level you just have to loop through the products and split the `x_no_of_likers` by separator you the likers per product

```
foreach($prods as $row):
$likers=explode('||',$row['x_no_of_likers']);
$total_likes= $row['total_likes'];
    foreach($likers as $user):
    ....
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Note  there is a default 1024 character limit set on `GROUP_CONCAT()` but you can also increase it by following the [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) manual

**Edit from comments** This is another way how to get n results per group, from this you can get all the fields from your user table i have used some variables to get the rank for product group ,used  subquery for `junction_table` to get the rank and in outer select i have filtered records with this rank using `HAVING jt.user_rank <=3` so it will give three users records per product ,i have also used subquery for products `(SELECT * FROM product LIMIT 30 )` so the first 30 groups will have 3 results for each,for below query limit cannot be used at the end so i have used in the subquery

```
SELECT p.id,p.title,u.firstname,u.lastname,u.thumbnail,jt.user_rank
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `product` LIMIT 30 ) p
LEFT JOIN 
 (  SELECT j.*,
   @current_rank:= CASE WHEN @current_rank = product_id THEN  @user_rank:=@user_rank +1 ELSE @user_rank:=1 END  user_rank,
   @current_rank:=product_id
    FROM `junction_table` j ,
    (SELECT @user_rank:=0,@current_rank:=0) r   
    ORDER BY product_id 
  ) jt ON(jt.product_id = p.id)
  LEFT JOIN `users` u ON (jt.`user_id` = u.`id`) 
  HAVING jt.user_rank <=3 
  ORDER BY p.id
```

### [Fiddle n results per group](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13a1f/8)

Comment: Hi Khalid, thanks for your answer. What if I want more than just the name of the liker? For instance, I actually need the username and thumbnail fields. Also, would you use this same method for showing comments on every product? ie. pinterest.com , facebook, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a list of all users that have liked all products with this sql.

```
select uid, 
       count(pid) as liked_products
  from product_user
 group by uid
having liked_products = (select count(1) from products);
```

But as data grows this query gets slow. Better then to maintain a table with like counts that is maintained through a trigger or separately. On every like/dislike the counter is updated. This makes it easy to show the number of likes for each product. Then if the actual users that liked that product is wanted do a separate call (on user interaction) that fetches the specific likes for one product). Don't do this for all products on a page until actually requested.

Comment: "Then if the actual users that liked that product is wanted do a separate call (on user interaction) that fetches the specific likes for one product)." Actually this is the subject of the question, whether or not it is feasible at all to show likes for all products on a product list page. So your suggestion is that this should never be done unless requested?

Comment: Correct. For a large number of products and a large number of customers it's not feasible. Better to do it "on demand" either when the customer clicks a link or as is getting very popular as the page scrolls down to the product.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the size of both these tables is non-trivially large. You should create a new table (say `LastThreeLikes`), where the columns would be `pid`,`uid_1`,`uid_2` and `uid_3`, indexed by `pid`. Also, add a column to your product table called `numLikes`.

For each "like" that you enter into your reference table, create a trigger that also populates this `LastThreeLikes` table if the `numLikes` is less than 3. You can choose to randomly update one of the values anyway if you want to show new users once in a while.

While displaying a product, simply fetch the `uid`s from this table and display them back.

Note that you also need to maintain a trigger for the "Unlike" action (if there is any) to re-populate the `LastThreeLikes` table with a new user id.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem is the volume of data. From the point of view that you need two integer value as a answer you should forget about building a heavy query from your n<->n relations table.

**Solution**

Generates a storable representation using the file_put_contents() with append option each time a user likes a product. I don't have enough room to write the class in here.

```
public function export($file);
```

**3D array format**

```
array[product][line][user]
```

Example:

```
$likes[1293][1][456]=1;
$likes[82][2][656]=1;
$likes[65][3][456]=1;
.
.
.
```

Number of users who like this particular product:

```
$number_users_like_this_product = count($likes[$idProduct]);
```

All idUser who like this particular product:

```
$users_like_this_product = count($likes[$idProduct][$n]);
```

All likes

```
$all_likes = count($likes);
```

**Deleting a like**

This loop will unset the only line where $idProduct and $IdUser you want. Since all the variables are unsigned integer it is very fast.

```
for($n=1, $n <= count($likes[$idProduct]), $n++)
{
 unset($likes[$idProduct][$n][$idUser]);
}
```

**Conclusion**

Get all likes will be easy as:

```
include('likes.php');
```

P.S If you want to give a try i will be glad to optimize my stuff and share it. I've created the class in 2012.