# Limit rows in SQL for each group with Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to limit the rows for each group of an output. What is the way to do it. Explaining the case below:

Table1: Customer_Details

`Customer       ID
Vandeur         pid_01
Vandeur         pid_02
Vandeur         pid_03
Vandeur         pid_04
Vandeur         pid_01
Vandeur         pid_02
Vandeur         pid_03
Vandeur         pid_04
Vandeur         pid_05`

Table2: Month_Details

`Month     ID
 Jan       pid_01
 Jan       pid_02
 Jan       pid_03
 Jan       pid_04
 Feb       pid_01
 Feb       pid_02
 Feb       pid_03
 Feb       pid_04
 Feb       pid_05`

My output requirement is - I want only first 3 IDs of each month for `customer` Vandeur

Sample O/P:

`Customer    Month    ID
Vandeur     Jan      pid_01
Vandeur     Jan      pid_02
Vandeur     Jan      pid_03
Vandeur     Feb      pid_01
Vandeur     Feb      pid_02
Vandeur     Feb      pid_03`

Can someone suggest me ways to achieve it.

Comment: sorry, it was miss. corrected. You know the ways to sort my issue?

Comment: A little hint  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677781/showing-users-who-liked-an-item-in-an-item-list

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, it's php solution.

Comment: I'd suggest to search SO with this statement: `MySQL ROW_NUMBER`, for example: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: @MaciejLos see another solution in accepted answer

Comment: Few mins back, I saw a post with `over partition by`. What happened to it?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql doesn't support window functions like other RDBMS,to get n results per group you can use user defined variables

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.Customer,m1.`Month`,c.ID
 FROM Customer_Details c
 JOIN (
  SELECT m.*,
   @r:= CASE WHEN @g = `Month` THEN  @r +1 ELSE 1 END  rank,
   @g:=`Month`
    FROM `Month_Details` m ,
    (SELECT @g:=NULL,@r:=NULL) r   
    ORDER BY m.`Month` DESC ,REPLACE(m.ID,'pid_','') * 1  
     ) m1 ON(c.ID = m1.ID)
  WHERE m1.rank <=3
 AND c.Customer= 'Vandeur'
 ORDER BY m1.`Month` DESC ,REPLACE(m1.ID,'pid_','') * 1
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19006/21)

Comment: The o/p is not limiting to 3. I could see entire set of values. `'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_01'
'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_01'
'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_02'
'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_02'
'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_03'
'Vandeur', 'Feb', 'pid_03'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_01'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_01'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_02'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_02'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_03'
'Vandeur', 'Jan', 'pid_03'
`

Comment: @user3624000 my bad use distinct and initialize variables with NULL